# About compiler and decompilation

Tags: android, decompiler

I want to prevent anyone from apk reverse compilation. We need to do something. I browsed on the internet, but I still don't know the operational steps clearly.

Who can tell me how to do it?

Anyone's help is so welcome!! Thanks!!

Comment: hi Matt Ellen ,i am so glad to get your help.just now, i have little time to ask this question.so i made many mistakes.thanks for your help.good luck

Comment: No worries. I only change things to try and get more people reading your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need an [obfuscator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code). If you are running .NET or Java, these should be easy to find.

There is nothing to prevent people from decompiling your code. All you can do is make it as nasty to read as possible. Don't do this in source (as you will not be able to modify your code yourself), use an obfuscator to do it as a post build step.

Answer (score 1):

Google recommends ProGuard. See [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html) in the Android docs for more information.

It won't prevent people from disassembling your code (you won't be able to stop that - after all, the operating system needs to disassemble your code to execute it!), but it will make it very hard to see what's going on.